# Will Excel Solver run faster with more CPU cores?

Tags: excel, performance, solver, cpu-cores

Different sources seem to give contrasting or unclear answers.

I'm running Excel solver that's working on equations in a spreadsheet with at least 16 columns and 1000 rows and a complicated equation in each cell, but would like to make it run even faster.

What will contribute more to its speed considering funding constraints: higher CPU clock speed or higher number of cores, both with hyperthreading enabled? (for example a 4.00GHz quad core or a 2.00 GHz octa core)

Thank you, and looking forward to your expert advise.

Comment: I don't know about Excel Solver but [Excel supports multithreading since Office 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687899.aspx)

Comment: I don't think Solver uses parallel algorithms. It is geared towards smallish LP, MIP and NLP problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try comparing solution times on your existing PC - first with all cores active, then switch off multi-threaded calc (File-->Option-->Advanced--> uncheck Enable multi-threaded calculation). That will allow you to see how efficiently your solver model makes use of multiple cores ( BTW real cores are what counts: hyper-threading only has a small effect). Assume a linear increase with CPU clock speed.

Also consider the professional version of Solver from FrontLine System.

Comment: Thanks! Will do this now.